# Which ways exist to improve rendering in Angular?

Tags: angular

Let's suppose we have a simple tree. It can contain any nested deep structure.

Changing one node of tree invokes all DOM changes (rendering), not only place where actions was happened. I wonder are there popular approaches to improve rendering performance or guide or principles which I must adhere?

For example, I know that so nested loops in template it is bad way.

Does Angular support cache?

Comment: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/06/angular-performances-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).OnPush in your components.

The 'default' strategy means: you press a button and Angular starts change detection cycle to check changes in the whole your page (and rerender it if there are some changes).

'OnPush' strategy means: you press a button and Angular detects changes only in components that depend from the button and the event.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
    ...,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {
...
}
```